# Access objects inside a class in Python

Tags: python, class, biopython

I have an object called SeqRecord from the package Biopython.

This object contains information in the following format:

```
ID: chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113
Name: chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113
Description: chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113 total_counts: 7600 Seed: 225 K: 20 length: 86
Number of features: 0
Seq('CACTCATGAGCTGTCCCCACATTAGGCTTAAAAACAGATGCAATTCCCGGACGT...ACC', SingleLetterAlphabet())
```

So it holds a sequence `Seq` and some other attributes: `ID`, `Name`,  `Description`, etc.

What I want is to count the different number of letters in the sequence. Something like:

```
Secuencia 0:
Number of A´s:
Number of C´s:
Number of G´s:
Number of T´s:
```

**What I´ve done so far?**

These objects usually have more than one sequence, so my idea was to firstly select all the sequences, and then, count numer of occurrences for each of them:

```
sequences=[]
for line in object:
   if line.startswith ("Seq"):
      sequences.append(line)
```

But this pops the next message:

`'SeqRecord' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

And I´ve tried other things but most python methods doesn´t operate with this object class.

Any idea how can I solve this with basic python?*

PD: * SeqRecord has some methods that allow you to this easily, but I want to do it with basic python functions

Comment: The Python standard library also has [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: `SeqRecord` doesn't know that method. It's not a string. You can call `dir()` on an object to see it's attributes (including its methods).

Comment: Could you explain more about why, if you have a `SeqRecord` object already and it provides a method that does what you want, you don't want to just call that method?

Comment: " python methods doesn´t operate with this object class." What? The problem is you are trying to treat this like a `str` object (not a "python object") but it isnt.

Comment: `for line in object:` wait, what?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga they named their list of records `object`, because somebody told them that everything in Python is an object but failed to tell them that you should never actually name something `object` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
sequences=[]
for line in object:
   if line.startswith ("Seq"):
      sequences.append(line)
```

According to the error message, it sounds like `object` (which is a bad variable name in a Python program because it shadows the builtin `object` type -- rename this!!!) is an iterable of `SeqRecord` objects, not an iterable of strings.  (You're confusing the `SeqRecord` object itself with the string that is produced when you `print` it -- in general it's much much easier to code against the methods provided by the actual object than to write lots of extra code to parse its string representation.)  To get the `Seq` objects you would do:

```
sequences = [record.seq for record in object]
```

(Again, assuming your list of `SeqRecords` is called `object` **which it should not be**, but you didn't provide the part of the code that assigns it to that name for me to be able to fix it.)

But since a `SeqRecord` itself implements iteration over the letters in the `Seq` (if I'm reading [the documentation](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.SeqRecord.html) correctly), you could count the occurrences of each letter in each sequence simply using `collections.Counter` on the `SeqRecord`s, without going through the extra step of extracting the `seq` from each one:

```
from collections import Counter

for i, sequence in enumerate(object):  # again, DO NOT EVER NAME OBJECTS 'object'
    print(f"Secuencia {i}:")
    for letter, count in Counter(sequence).items():
        print(f"Number of {letter}'s: {count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your input SeqRecord

I created one

check here: [Asking Better Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/)

Using Biopython :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 31 16:37:39 2020

@author: Pietro
"""




from Bio.Seq import Seq

from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

from collections import Counter

seqrecordmine = SeqRecord(Seq("CACTCATGAGCTGTCCCCACATTAGGCTTAAAAACAGATGCAATTCCCGGACGT"),id="chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113",
name=" chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113",
description=" chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113 total_counts: 7600 Seed: 225 K: 20 length: 86")


print(seqrecordmine)

for letter, count in Counter(seqrecordmine.seq).items(): #SeqRecord.seq = seq is a property of SeqRecord objects/Class
        print(f"Number of {letter}'s: {count}")
```

Result:

```
ID: chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113
Name:  chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113
Description:  chr1_8969882_-:chr1_568670_-:a1;113 total_counts: 7600 Seed: 225 K: 20 length: 86
Number of features: 0
Seq('CACTCATGAGCTGTCCCCACATTAGGCTTAAAAACAGATGCAATTCCCGGACGT')
Number of C's: 16
Number of A's: 16
Number of T's: 12
Number of G's: 10
```